# How to override a child's parameter in <include>

Tags: android, xml

I want to include the following layout in another XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

I know I can override the layout parameters of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the  tag. For example:

```
<include android:id="@+id/news_title"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         layout="@layout/title"/>
```

My question is: what should I do to override the child's parameter? E.g. here if I want to override `android:text="@string/hello"`of the `TextView`, what should I do?

Comment: Those are called attributes in XML, by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't-  you can only override layout_* parameters of the root view of the include.  You'd need to do it in code by searching for the id (assuming you only do it once).  Your other option is to make a custom View class that inflates the included layout into itself (probably with a merge tag to avoid an extra level of views) which can then look at the attribute set passed down during inflation and do what it needs to with it.